# Cannot implicity convert type char to string

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to use my `GetChar` method to keep displaying the prompt and reading whatever the user typed on the keyboard until `Char.TryParse` can convert the input to an char But I keep getting an error

> Cannot implicity convert type char to string

when I call my `GetChar` method.

Any help would be appreciated

```
// Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
static void ProcessCreate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
{
        //Int32 player = 0;
        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {
          number = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
                       //Console.ReadLine();
            if (GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount) == -1)
            {
                firstName = IOConsole.GetChar("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's First Name");
                  //Console.ReadLine();
                  lastName = IOConsole.GetChar("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's Last  Name");
                 //Console.ReadLine();
                 goals = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's goals");
               Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               assists = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's assists");
                 //Console.ReadLine();
                InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
              players[player].Number, players[player].FirstName, players[player].LastName,
              players[player].Goals, players[player].Assists, players[player].Points());

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");
    }
```

Here is my `GetChar` method

```
public static char GetChar(String prompt)
{
        // declare variables
        char validChar;

        while (!Char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out validChar))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entery - try again.");
            Console.Write(prompt);
        }

        return validChar;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (!Char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out validChar))
```

In this line you are reading string data, not single char, so you can't assign it to 'validChar' (method Console.ReadLine).
Try assigning invocation of this method to the string variable, then use index [] operator to get first of the characters.

Alternatively you can use

```
public static ConsoleKeyInfo ReadKey()
```